# Static variable out of scope, Error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, static, scope

the Error is:

> cannot find symbol `System.out.println("value of count" + count);`

Symbol:

> variable count

Location:

> class synchronize

I declared `count` variable `static` so doesn't that mean every class can access it?

```
class a extends Thread 

{

public static int count=0;

public void run()

 {

   for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){

   count++;
    }
  }
}

class b extends Thread {

public void run(){

  for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){

  count++;
  }
 }
}

class synchronize {

public static void main(String args[]) {

  a obj =new a();

  b obj1=new b();

  obj.start();

  obj1.start();

  System.out.println("value of count "+count) ;

 }
}
```

Comment: Please make count globally static.

Comment: Try `a.count` instead of `count`

Comment: `static` means that a variable does not belong to any particular instance of a given class, but to the class iteself.  It's usually referenced through its class name. Like `ClassName.variable`.

Comment: Am using a.count() now it's showing cannot find symbol count. Location class. :b. Please help

Comment: Use `a.count`, not `a.count()`. With the parentheses, it looks for a static method called `count` in your `a` class, which does not exist.

Comment: @user187744 I have addressed your new problem in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

the `count` variable is declared as a member of the `a` class.

So if you change:

```
System.out.println("value of count "+count);
```

To:

```
System.out.println("value of count " + a.count);
```

So that you are accessing the `count` variable as a member of the `a` class, then your `synchornize` class should be able to 'see' the `count` variable.

Also, you may want to use the `a.count` inside of class `b` as well:

```
class b extends Thread {

    public void run(){

      for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){

          a.count++;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's a `static` member of class `a`, so it's better to refer to it statically: `a.count`. (I'd also suggest that OP rename the classes to start with upper case letters, so as to conform to Java conventions.)

Answer (score 2):

Static variables have a single value for all instances of a class.

You have to access static variables by class name

instead of this

```
System.out.println("value of count "+count) ;
```

use this

```
System.out.println("value of count "+a.count) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it is public and static, you are correct in that you will be able to access the `count` variable in your `a` class from anywhere in your code.

However, you cannot access it just by using the variable `count`.

Your other classes do not know about any `count` variable, but they know about your `a` class. So you can use `a.count` to access the `count` variable in your `a` class from any of your other classes.

Comment: Thank you very much all of you